# Formato en fechas

Tags: java

Tengo esta parte de codigo, y necesito que el metodo `get` de ambas fechas cambie el formato. Lo que hago es pasar a String y luego estoy intentando cambiar el formato de alguna manera, pero se me esta complicando mas de la cuenta...

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Parking {

    private GregorianCalendar fechaEntrada; 
    private GregorianCalendar fechaSalida;
    private final double pago;

    Calendar hoy = Calendar.getInstance();

    public Parking() {

        this.pago = 0.35; // VARIABLE CONSTANTE PARA NO VARIAR. PRECIO A PAGAR POR MIN.
    }

    public void setFechaEntrada(int anio, int mes, int dia, int hora, int minuto) {

         this.fechaEntrada = new GregorianCalendar(anio, mes, dia, hora, minuto);
    }

    public void setFechaSalida(int anio, int mes, int dia, int hora, int minuto) {

         this.fechaSalida = new GregorianCalendar(anio, mes, dia, hora, minuto);
    }


    public String getfechaEntrada() {

        return fechaEntrada.toString();
    }

    public String getfechaSalida() {

        return fechaSalida.toString();
    }
```

¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo? Soy un poco novata usando fechas, parecia mas facil de lo que me imaginè :S

Comment: Utiliza `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 4):

Si, hay una forma simple de hacerlo.

Debes de crear un formato y aplicarlo a la salida de las fechas o donde quieras aplicarlo. Seria de esta forma:

```
formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
```

En los parametros puedes cambiar la forma en la que se muestran los datos, por ejemplo, si no te interesa, puedes eliminar las horas y minutos...

Tu ejercicio queda de esta forma:

```
public class Parking {

    private GregorianCalendar fechaEntrada; 
    private GregorianCalendar fechaSalida;
    private final double pago;
    private SimpleDateFormat formato;

    Calendar hoy = Calendar.getInstance();

    public Parking() {

        this.pago = 0.35; // VARIABLE CONSTANTE PARA NO VARIAR. PRECIO A PAGAR POR MIN.
        formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"); // FORMATO PARA LA FECHA.
    }

    public void setFechaEntrada(int anio, int mes, int dia, int hora, int minuto) {

         this.fechaEntrada = new GregorianCalendar(anio, mes, dia, hora, minuto);
    }

    public void setFechaSalida(int anio, int mes, int dia, int hora, int minuto) {

         this.fechaSalida = new GregorianCalendar(anio, mes, dia, hora, minuto);
    }


    public String getfechaEntrada() {

        String fecha = formato.format(fechaEntrada.getTime());
        return fecha;
    }

    public String getfechaSalida() {

        String fecha = formato.format(fechaSalida.getTime());
        return fecha;
    }
```

Asi que no es necesario pasar la fecha a String e intertar tu misma cambiar el formato manualmente, teniendo esto.

Un placer ayudarte.